# Height or length of flagpole

Tags: word-usage

> The flagpole was prodeced with the height/length of 10 feets.

Which one should I use in sentence above “length or height? As the flagpole is produced horizontally I think I should use length ? But I couldn’t be sure ?

Comment: I suppose you could use “length” here, and your reasoning about it being horizontally produced or constructed is sensible, but the sentence sounds a bit forced or unnatural to me as a native speaker. “Produced” is less idiomatic than “made” in this sort of context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this question is really about English at all, but I would still describe the flagpole's (intended) vertical dimension as its **height**. The orientation of the pole during manufacturing is irrelevant and quite likely unknown to the reader/listener.

Comment: I'm not so sure. A flagpole has to be either set into the ground or bolted into a support. I would say that the _height_ of the flagpole is either the _ length_ of the pole less the portion sunk into the ground or the _length_ of the pole plus the portion of the support below the pole. The length of the pole is the distance from the base to the tip regardless of its orientation.

Comment: Possibly a portion of the length is in a hole in the ground, but even so: sticking up, height; lying on the ground, length.